# Automatizar respuesta a la consola desde mandatos (BASH)

Tags: bash, consola

Utilizando este mandato dentro de un script:

```
sudo mdadm --create $var0 --level=$var1 --raid-devices=$dipo $var2
```

Me sale por consola al realizarlo el siguiente mensaje:

```
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
Continue creating array?
```

Se tiene que contestar y/n, pero no me deja poner en las opciones del mandato -y para contestar automáticamente, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo para que se confirme la orden dentro del script?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: yo diría que es peligroso lo que pides, pues si te fijas bien en lo que dice te puedes cargar el /boot si continuas. Por lo que dice su [documentación](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) por defecto usa metadata=1.2 y en ese mensaje de error te estan recomendando 0.90.  Aún así puedes probar con --force a ver si cuela o bien editar el mdadm.conf tal como indican en el enlace anterior.

Comment: aún así, tienes otra curiosa opcion que puedes usar, que es el comando **yes** y que se ejecutaria así supongo:  `sudo yes | mdadm --create $var0 --level=$var1 --raid-devices=$dipo $var2`  (eso responderia **y** a todo lo que le pida), o bien lo contrario, que seria sudo yes n | mdadm --create $var0 --level=$var1 --raid-devices=$dipo $var2`

Comment: Hola, Gracias por las respuestas! Estoy en una maq virtual asi que sin problemas, la solucion con --force me ha funcionado!